# (Sums of dependent random variables) This problems develops a central limit theorem for a sum of dependent random variables

Tags: time-series, probability, autoregressive, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be i.i.d. r.v.s with zero mean and unit variance. Define $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n X_jX_{j+1}$.

(a) Show $Var(Z_n) = 1$

(b) Show $Z_n \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hint: First condition on the $X_j$ for $j$ odd. Verify the conditional uniform asymptotic negligibility condition (UAN: $\max_j \sigma_j/s_n \to 0, s_n^2 = Var(\sum_j X_jX_{j+1})$) using the law of large numbers and boundedness to obtain a conditional limiting result. Then show that unconditional convergence follows.

**My question:** Part (a) is easily verified to be 1 via the standard variance-covariance formula. My issue is with the second part. I see why they want us to condition on $j$ odd: it eliminates the terms where there is a possibility of overlap, namely if $j$ is odd, then $X_jX_{j+1}$ would be an odd-even pair, and no other terms in the summation will overlap. I don't understand why this is necessary and where exactly LLN is used. Suppose we try to prove the UAN condition directly by showing $\max_j \sigma_j^2/s_n^2 \to 0$. We obtain:
$$
\frac{\max_j \sigma^2}{s_n^2}
=
\frac{\max_j Var(X_jX_{j+1})}{Var(\sum_j X_jX_{j+1})}
=
\frac{1}{Var(\sqrt{n}Z_n)}
=
\frac{1}{n}
\to 0.
$$
I must be doing something wrong here because I didn't have to use the LLN or boundedness. In the numerator, $Var(X_jX_{j+1}) = E[X_j^2X_{j+1}^2] - (E[X_jX_{j+1}]^2) = 1 - 0 = 1$ by the independence of $X_j$ and $X_{j+1}$.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the hint wanted you to work with the variable $Z_n^{\ast} = \sqrt{n} Z_n | \{X_j = x_j: j \mbox{ is odd}\}$?  For $n$ even, one may write $Z_n^{\ast} = \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} X_{2i} (x_{2i-1} + x_{2i+1})$, and we have $n/2$ independent terms where the $i$th term has variance $(x_{2i-1} + x_{2i+1})^2$.  I am unsure if it makes sense to state that $\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} (x_{2i-1} + x_{2i+1})^2 \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 2$ by the LLN after the conditioning step since they would be treated as constants?

Comment: @user277126 I think your assumption is correct for $Z_n^*$. The conditional UAN is confusing to me as well. I just don't see why they'd want us to split things in this way if the calculation I wrote works fine. I think that my calculation for the UAN must be incorrect then.

Comment: I am not too familiar with it.  I had some exposure to Lindeberg's condition which is closely related.  One thing to note, when I looked up examples of using the UAN as well as Lindeberg's condition, it required the variables in the summation to be independent.  Perhaps this is why you have to split the sum